# An intuitive explanation of the relationship between general relativity and the scale factor

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

With as little math as possible your understanding of the how the scale factor and general relativity relate. Is the premise that the cosmic scale factor is a consequence of the calculations of GR or was the scale factor introduced to make GR align with observational data? I would welcome as many nuanced explanations as possible from as many sources as possible. A single answer, no matter how well written, can include all viewpoints.

Comment: Your question isn't as clear on what it wants as you probably wanted it to be. You want little math, but also nuance citing multiple sources. You want to include "all" viewpoints (how "all" are we talking? Here we deal in mainstream physics), but the question is about how a spacetime geometry with a scale factor emerges from applying GR to cosmology. That's actually not a very controversial question at all. I recommend editing your question to focus on what you're after.

Comment: Having said that, on the interpretation of your question that makes it best-suited to the site, here's my answer: if you apply the Einstein field equations in a spatially homogeneous isotropic universe, you get [not only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Assumptions) a metric with a scale factor, but [two differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Equations) in which it features.

Comment: The number of independent astronomical observables we have completely determine the FRW geometry, so we fit the data assuming FRW geometry. In general, these limited observables do not completely determine a generic lumpy universe model (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157385900304?via%3Dihub)), nor it necessarily implies that our universe is FRW at cosmological scale

Answer (score 1):

The occurrence of a time-dependent scale factor is a direct consequence of the assumption that the geometry be isotropic and spatially homogeneous at each time. So, it's the same scaling in all spatial directions at all locations, hence a uniform, but time-dependent, scale factor; with the spatial dimensions being either flat, or uniformly curved with either positive or negative curvature.

Those assumptions are purely geometric.

The only thing General Relativity brings to bear, here, is (1) relating the geometry to the matter content of the universe and (2) determining the time-dependency of the scale factor. Those are the points where the Einstein equations are used.

Various restrictions or constraints on what kinds of matter content may be employed, from whatever theories of matters are being used, which will limit the range of possible geometries.

More general geometries, like those in the Bianchi classification, may be also considered as a starting assumption, instead.